# When test Auto-Renewable subscription Sandbox account ask for credential as app launch. Is this also happen after application live?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, subscription, storekit

I implemented Auto renewable subscription using RMStore.

In home screen (After launch) I implement the functionality for verify user.
But with sandbox its ask apple id and password. So how to resolve this.

Also I want to know that the same think happen after application approved by app store ?

Answer (score 0):

As i can understand its happening just because of your uncompleted transactions.
So if you want to resolve this issue you must have to finish your all uncompleted transaction.
You can use below code to finish your transactions. Put below code inside

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        for transaction:SKPaymentTransaction in SKPaymentQueue.default().transactions {
            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
        }
    }
```

Comment: but this behaviour will same after application approved and available on appStore ?

Comment: May your purchase code not finish all transactions. You must have to call self.queue.finishTransaction(transaction) on each transaction.

Comment: but this is happen on when I refreshReceipt. Till now I didn't make any purchase or transaction call.

Comment: As per user standard you don't have to refresh receipt on each launches. you can refresh receipt on purchase or restoration.